# Exclude from the query posts with meta_key and meta_value

Tags: functions, query-posts, post-meta

I use this function to exclude from the query posts that are 30 days old,

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
  //posts in the last 30 days
  $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
  return $where;
}
// Register the filtering function
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
// Perform the query, the filter will be applied automatically
query_posts($query_string);
```

is it possible to do something like this to exclude posts that have a meta_key=votes and meta_value=0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to add a posts_join filter, to join the posts and postmeta tables.

This link should be helpful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries, in particular this piece of example code:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'geotag_search_join' );
add_filter('posts_where', 'geotag_search_where' );

function geotag_search_join( $join )
{
  global $geotag_table, $wpdb;

  if( is_search() ) {
    $join .= " LEFT JOIN $geotag_table ON " . 
       $wpdb->posts . ".ID = " . $geotag_table . 
       ".geotag_post_id ";
  }

  return $join;
}

function geotag_search_where( $where )
{
  if( is_search() ) {
    $where = preg_replace(
       "/\(\s*post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
       "(post_title LIKE $1) OR (geotag_city LIKE $1) OR (geotag_state LIKE $1) OR (geotag_country LIKE $1)", $where );
   }

  return $where;
}
```

Comment: Probably the right approach for now. And in this case, your WHERE clause would be testing for IS NULL or <> "0".

Answer (score 2):

Or, in WP3.1:

```
$query['meta_query'] = array(
    'key' => 'votes',
    'value' => '0',
    'compare' => '!='
    ),
```